# Best practice for storing and accessing common string literals

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best approach for storing some string literals to be used throughout a large project? I don't want devs writing the literals in more than one place for obvious reasons. I also, don't want a bunch of redundant/useless code. I'm looking for the cleanest/simplest way to have a small list of string literals that are easily accessible (meaning they have a declarative name like `status.passed = "passed"` not `status[0] = "passed"`) and are stored in a sensible way. An `enum` would be ideal but they can't take strings, and the dictionary + enum solutions I've seen here don't appeal to me.

Would a static class be the best choice?

Comment: If they need to be localized (or ever *will* need to be), use a `resx` file.  Otherwise, use const strings in a static class or struct.

Comment: Please give an example of how an enum does not take a string.

Comment: @Blam: how do you provide an example of something that can't be done? :-) anyway: `Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Blam `enum status { Passed = "passed" }` will not compile. Neither will `enum status : string { Passed = "passed" }`. Maybe there's something I'm missing?

Comment: @JuliánUrbano Pretty easy you post the desired syntax that fails.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I will post an answer.

Comment: @Blam Alright, ty. Although resx is probably better practice I'm kind of apposed to it. I only have 4 strings, they're not going to change, I don't care if a change requires a rebuild (internal utils so rebuild is nbd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure enum will not do what you need?

```
namespace EnumTest
{
    public enum enumRole : byte { projMgr = 2, docAdmin = 3, dataAdmin = 4, sysAdmin = 9, userAdmin = 5 };
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            enumRole myrole = enumRole.docAdmin;
            if (myrole == enumRole.docAdmin) Console.WriteLine("I am docAdmin");
            // i use the key to save to SQL and restore  
            // in SQL have a fk table to match the enum
            Console.WriteLine((byte)myrole);
            myrole = (enumRole)9;
            Console.WriteLine(myrole.ToString() + " " + ((byte)myrole).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `enum.ToString` does not work for arbitrary strings, it just gives you the name of the enum variable. For example, it can't be `Project Admin`.

Comment: If they are arbitrary strings then I agree.  But "I only have 4 strings, they're not going to change, I don't care if a change requires a rebuild (internal utils so rebuild is nbd)" is not what I would call arbitrary strings.

Comment: Yeah +1, this is actually a fine solution for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 8):

You should use a [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (.resx) file.

Answer (score 1):

Use Constants in this case

or

a resource file (*.resx).